# Is there a way to create autoincrement key via Oracle Create Table Gui?

Tags: oracle, key, auto-increment, toad

I create tables with using TOAD Create Table GUI. I want to create autoincrement key. I don't want to write sql of it. Is there any way to do this on GUI screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find any way to do it through the GUI. I am not much of an oracle user. worked with it only once. But it can be easily done by creating sequences and triggers.

Comment: OK I realized. There is no way do it directly unlike mysql. I create sequence and do it. Thanks.